# Deleted OS OnePlus One

Tags: android, adb

Last week, while updating my phone, something went wrong resulting in my phone not booting properly. When turning on the phone it got stuck on the OPO logo. Thus, I first tried to wipe cache, didn't work. Then I tried something else and accidentally deleted the "system" data. I was now looking for a way to put the OS back on my phone with terminal (I work on Mac). The problem is that my computer doesn't detect my phone (when typing "adb devices"), and I think it is because the ADB-debugging box in the developer tools isn't checked on my phone. The problem is that I cannot check that box because I can't boot my system.

Who has a suggesting for what to do?

Thanks in advance,

Gijs

Comment: This is a wrong Stack, try this: https://android.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

There is a thing like ADB called Fastboot mode. Look up how to boot your oneplus into fastboot mode (it's just a key combo) and then you can do things that you could on ADB with fastboot like loading a new ROM.

Comment: Yes, I am familiar with the Fastboot mode I and tried that. But in order for my computer to detect the phone the USB-debugging should be enabled, but I now cannot reach that option. When I'm in terminal and typing "adb devices" it doesn't detect my OPO.